# C# Sqllocaldb Error26

Tags: c#, localdb

I have coded a program in C# that uses sqllocaldb. The program works great on my machine (win7-sp1).

However I couldn't run it on other machines. It gives 26 error messages. I have installed sqllocaldb and created instance. I can't connect with `data source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb` but I can connect using its pipe name. The other problem is that whenever I restarts the PC I have to start instance manually but not on my own PC, it starts autamatically. What am I missing?

P.S. program uses .NET 3.5.

There are .NET 4.5, 4.5.1, 4.5.2, and 4.6.1 on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

I  think your best bet is to update your application to use .NET 4.0

There is this update for .NET 3.5 support for LocalDB: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2664825/an-update-is-available-that-adds-support-for-microsoft-sql-server-express-localdb-to-the-.net-framework-3.5.1-in-windows-7-sp1-and-in-windows-server-2008-r2-sp1 - sadly, it requires Visual Studio 2012 to be installed...